# Losing variable value when trying to copy file using mailReader.php

Tags: php

I'm using the mailReader script found here: https://github.com/stuporglue/mailreader

I am trying to copy the file(s) after upload to another folder.
The file(s) upload correctly to the folder where the script resides.
When I try to run a copy command, the filename variable is empty.

Here is the portion of the code I am working with: The last three lines are what I added.

```
private function saveFile($filename,$contents,$mimeType = 'unknown'){
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/','_',$filename);

    $unlocked_and_unique = FALSE;
    while(!$unlocked_and_unique){
        // Find unique
        $name = time() . "_" . $filename;
        $name = substr_replace($name,".pdf",-4); // added 1-19-2016
        while(file_exists($this->save_directory . $name)) {
            $name = time() . "_" . $filename;
            $name = substr_replace($name,".pdf",-4);
        }
        // Attempt to lock
        $outfile = fopen($this->save_directory.$name,'w');
        if(flock($outfile,LOCK_EX)){
            $unlocked_and_unique = TRUE;
        }else{
            flock($outfile,LOCK_UN);
            fclose($outfile);
        }
    }
    fwrite($outfile,$contents);
    fclose($outfile);

    if (copy($this->save_directory.$name, "/attachments/" . TRANS_ID . "/". $name)) {
        unlink( $this->save_directory.$name );
    }
```

I receive confirmation by email that the file(s) are uploaded, then another email with the error message.

> Warning:  copy(/attachments/W7652222-546/1453406138_residential-print_from_td.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myhost/public_html/mailreader/mailReader.php on line 224

224 being the line number of my added code.

The source filename is missing from in front of /attachments...

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think the filename variable is empty? The error message just says that the destination directory doesn't exist. `copy` will create the destination file, but it won't create the `W7652222-546`.

Comment: The file exists in the source directory and the destination folder does exist: (/attachments/W7652222-546/1453465663_residential-nitro.pdf)

Comment: I receive the exact same error with your modified code.

Answer (score 0):

$name is defined in the while loop and may not be accessible on the upper scopes my suggestion is to change your code to this:

```
private function saveFile($filename,$contents,$mimeType = 'unknown'){
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/','_',$filename);

    $unlocked_and_unique = FALSE;
    $name = '';
    while(!$unlocked_and_unique){
        // Find unique
        $name = time() . "_" . $filename;
        $name = substr_replace($name,".pdf",-4); // added 1-19-2016
        while(file_exists($this->save_directory . $name)) {
            $name = time() . "_" . $filename;
            $name = substr_replace($name,".pdf",-4);
        }
        // Attempt to lock
        $outfile = fopen($this->save_directory.$name,'w');
        if(flock($outfile,LOCK_EX)){
            $unlocked_and_unique = TRUE;
        }else{
            flock($outfile,LOCK_UN);
            fclose($outfile);
        }
    }
    fwrite($outfile,$contents);
    fclose($outfile);

    if (copy($this->save_directory.$name, "/attachments/" . TRANS_ID . "/". $name)) {
        unlink( $this->save_directory.$name );
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: PHP variables have function scope, not block scope.

Comment: The variable should be available (it never gets resetted), but it could hold the wrong value after the loop

Comment: @Alex2php It contains the last value of `$name`, which is the one that it successfully opened and locked.

Comment: @Alex2php what is strange is that is that the error shows the destination part of the copy command, but the source is empty. Both use the $name variable.

Comment: The destination path is created in the beginning of the code.

    chdir("attachments/");
         if (!file_exists($trans_id)) { mkdir($trans_id, 0777); }
      chdir("..");

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining a constant of email_id in the private function saveToDb, then running a script after everything else is finished to query the table using the email_id and looping through the records moving the files.